# Make Notification bar gradient and navigation bar black at the same time

Tags: android

I can create a transparent notif+nav bar and then set below the notif bar a custom view that has a gradient background. This is ok.

But how can I create a nav bar that is black, and not transparent at the same time? (So: gradient notif bar+black filled nav bar)

Is it possible?

Here is my old code

```
 fun setTransparentNotificationBar(window: Window) {
        with(window) {
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the answer is:

```
    with(window) {
        clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    }
```